# how to design a reducer that needs to change each second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, timer

I'm trying to make a timer app, each timer has a time that decrements until it finishes(gets to 0) and a sound plays:
[image: my timers]

the initial state of each timer has a property, named `passing`:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  ... 
  passing: false 
};
```

for each timer, if its `passing` is true, each second I call `pass action` to decrement its time:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  if(timer.passing){ 
     this.pass(timer.id) 
  } 
}

pass = (id)=>{ 
  setInterval(()=>{
    this.props.pass(id)
  }, 1000)
};
```

my `reducer`:

```
case PASS:
  let newTimers = [];
  state.timers.map(timer=>{
    if(timer.id === action.payload){
      const {hours, minutes, seconds} = timer.time;
      if(hours < 1 && minutes < 1 && seconds < 1){
         timer.passing = false;
         timer.alarm = true;
      }else if(timer.time.seconds === 0){
         if(timer.time.minutes === 0){
            timer.time.hours--;
            timer.time.minutes = 59;
            timer.time.seconds = 59;
         }else{
            timer.time.minutes--;
            timer.time.seconds = 59;
         }
      }else{
         timer.time.seconds--;
      }
    }
    newTimers.push(timer);
  });
  return {...state, timers: newTimers};
```

this approach is ok when I just start a single timer, but as soon as I start multiple timers, just one of them works, because multiple `pass actions` are called at the same time.

So how can I make my reducer to update itself, without me having to call actions each second?

> remember there is no specific target time like 4 pm, etc. because the
>   user may tap on stop button and hold the timer for some hours and then
>   tap on start(continue). so getting the current time and calculate the remaining time to the
>   target time can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to create a reducer to change every second, you need to dispatch the proper action inside the interval in your component.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that one problem is that you are calling `this.pass` on `componentDidUpdate`, which will cascade into many `setInterval` updates and mess up the timers. Try doing it on `componentDidMount` instead with the timer's `passing` and `id` coming from `props`. `forceUpdate` also seems necessary when working with intervals.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.props.pass(this.props.id);
      this.forceUpdate(); // seems like you need this in setInterval
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyjz8jzp45) with a basic working example of your use case.

Comment: before each interval, I clear the previous one, so there is no mess! since componentDidMount just triggers once if I put it there and user click on the stop button, it won't stop

Comment: you could clear the interval when the user hits the stop button and set it again when the user starts it again. either way, the general approach you're using should work. did you look at the CodeSandbox?

Comment: yes, I did thanks. but in fact what you solved is not my problem, the thing is that since multiple pass actions are called in multiple components simultaneously, just one of them works. on the other hand, if we go with your solution if after stopping and clearing the interval, if the user clicks on start again my component won't trigger componentDidMount, so I have to use componentDidMount